# Vim programming editor speed

Tags: vim

**Problem is: [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) gets slow when I add the following lines to my [vimrc](/questions/tagged/vimrc):**

```
set foldmethod=syntax 
set foldlevelstart=1 
let javaScript_fold=1 " JavaScript 
let perl_fold=1 " Perl 
let php_folding=1 " PHP 
let r_syntax_folding=1 " R 
let ruby_fold=1 " Ruby 
let sh_fold_enabled=1 " sh 
let vimsyn_folding='af' " Vim script 
let xml_syntax_folding=1 " XML
```

Context: *whilst editing a* [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) *file*

I think it's fair enough for it to slow down when:

- opening a new file, recalculating syntax-based folds (e.g. collapse function defs)
- creating a new function definition

... but... for it to do so *everywhere*?

Do you use/see the same? What could be done to ameliorate the sluggishness, if anything?

---

*It took me a day to identify this, successfully reproduce it anywhere on my (virtual and non-) machines, eliminating candidate contributors to overall slowness by a process of* [vimrc](/questions/tagged/vimrc) *binary search.*

---

#### My environment

[vim](/questions/tagged/vim) **VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 12 2013 14:05:25)**

[osx](/questions/tagged/osx) **OS X v10.8.3 (build 12D78)**

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) **v3.2.48(1)-release**

---

Comment: Fear not, questions about programming tools are on topic.  Feel free to remove your preamble.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with some [auto commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html). Turning on features depending on the type of files, vim can speed up. Example:

```
autocmd BufRead *.pt set filetype=xml
au FileType xml setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set foldmethod=indent
```

is much faster and works more reliably and in a more predictable manner across languages than `syntax`.

Also, what is the point of adding `" PHP` after `let php_folding=1`?

Anyway, you should get yourself [a proper Vim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/): the one provided with Mac OS X is both outdated and crippled. Using the latest available version may not fix your issue but it provides the best baseline for asking and providing help.

Comment: I use `macports`, I was never able to figure out `brew` (shame on me). Is `macports` an _acceptable vim_, by your account? I might as well start by switching versions..

Comment: I _copied_ that `" PHP` from the web, if you Google for it, you'll see I plagiarised my "vim folding section"! Can you give me a better "vim folding section" to copy word by word?

Comment: 1. Brew is not better than MacPorts. It's more fashionable but not intrinsically better: if you have no problem with MacPorts and are not a hipster, switching to brew is worthless. 2. MacPorts Vim is OK but I simply use a downloaded MacVim. That's the same version anyway. 3. Copying other people's config is not the right way to go. You are supposed to identify a need and read `:help` to find out how to suit it. And read `:help` whenever you find something interesting online. 4. That line in my answer is the only fold-related setting in my `~/.vimrc`: i've never found a reason to complain.